# Other software checkboxes in software sources are not working after update to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, software-sources

When I'm trying to enable some sources in **Other Software** in **Software Sources** I see an auth prompt, but when I put in my password, I see no changes of checkboxes states. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: And yes, I know how to do it with command line, I just want to have my GUI in working state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot enable canonical partner and independent, why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314419/i-cannot-enable-canonical-partner-and-independent-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and type

```
sudo -H nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Delete all files that have an extension `.DistUpgrade`

Rename `.list` and `.list.save` files by changing the older release name(`precise`) to the new one(`quantal`)

This solved it for me.

Comment: Knowing why this helps and what actually happens by doing this might improve this answer.