# I cannot enable canonical partner and independent, why?

Tags: software-sources

On Software and Updates under Other Software tab, I want to enable Canonical Partner and Independent, after I clicked the checkbox and input my password, the checkbox stay unchecked no matter how many times I try to click it, why?
I'm on Raring.

Comment: You can also see this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/how-do-i-enable-the-partner-repository#new-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main"
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go back to Software and Updates, and check to see if its OK

Note: in the second command replace raring with your Ubuntu version.

Comment: On second line I got : Error: 'deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu' invalid

Comment: I've fixed the command.  see answer, and let me know.  Thanks

Comment: Works, but now in Software and Updates there are 2 Canonical Partner and 2 Independent, the original (on the top) is still unchecked, should I remove them?

Comment: I've got the same, and I left them alone.

Comment: As long they do no harm to my system I'll leave them alone, thanks!

Comment: They won't I've had like this a long time.

Answer (score 5):

The bug is Ubuntu failing to display an authentication prompt. A potential solution to this is simply to run the software as root:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

It's also possible (as @Abdel-Rahman notes) to edit the `sources.list` file directly. The software-properties-gtk application does just edit that file, commenting or uncommenting the line as needed. Using `add-apt-repository` will duplicate this line, and have no effect on the authentication bug: it's not actively harmful, but it's not a preferable solution.

Comment: Bug link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1727908

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution works fine alternatively you can navigate to and edit sources.list file directly from terminal using

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

find the line that says

```
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

remove the comment and save(Ctrl+X), and you're done.

Comment: The question and accepted answer is about `raring` and your answer is about `bionic`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that detail aside, editing the file directly is almost certainly the better solution than the accepted answer. The issue is that gnome-shell is failing to display an authentication prompt.